Polars - groupby mean on list
I want to make mean on groups of embeddings vectors.
For examples:
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,1 ,2,2],
    "values": [
        [1,1,1], [3, 3, 3],
        [1,1,1], [2, 2, 2]
    ]
})

shape: (4, 2)
id  values
i64 list[i64]
1   [1, 1, 1]
1   [3, 3, 3]
2   [1, 1, 1]
2   [2, 2, 2]

Expected result.
import numpy as np

pl.DataFrame({
    "id":[1,2],
    "values": np.array([
        [[1,1,1], [3, 3, 3]],
        [[1,1,1], [2, 2, 2]]
    ]).mean(axis=1)
})

shape: (2, 2)
id  values
i64 list[f64]
1   [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
2   [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]



int_ranges() to create ordinality for lists.
explode() to explode lists.
group_by() twice, first to calculate mean() and then to combine results into lists.

(
    df
    .with_columns(i = pl.int_ranges(pl.col.values.list.len()))
    .explode('values', 'i')
    .group_by('id', 'i', maintain_order = True)
    .mean()
    .group_by('id', maintain_order = True)
    .agg('values')
)

┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ values          │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ list[f64]       │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [2.0, 2.0, 2.0] │
│ 2   ┆ [1.5, 1.5, 1.5] │
└─────┴─────────────────┘


something is strange - I am getting different results every run

are your lists length is fixed or different for different ids?

fixed size - it's embeddings vectors

ok, not sure that's the problem, but I should've definitely set maintain_order = True in group_by method (or sort by i during aggregation). Updated the answer, could you check please?
